# How can I check if a Perl module is installed on my system from the command line?

Tags: perl, command-line, perl-module

I tried to check if XML::Simple is installed in my system or not.

```
perl -e 'while (<@INC>) { while (<$_/*.pm>) { print "$_\n"; } }'
```

The above one-liner was used for listing all modules installed in my system. However, it is not listing XML modules.

However, the following executes fine.

```
perl -e "use XML::Simple "
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: @Sinan: you changed the question a bit too much. I think the original question was how to find out where a module is installed. Now it's whether a module is installed.

Comment: I really have no idea. But considering the current question, your answer is pretty much the best so far. 
Maybe Chells can enlighten us.

Comment: @Sinan: why'd you retag from perl-module to perl-modules when the latter is barely used?

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/check-for-installed-modules-in-perl.html

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can check for a module's installation path by:

```
perldoc -l XML::Simple
```

The problem with your one-liner is that, it is not recursively traversing directories/sub-directories. Hence, you get only pragmatic module names as output.

Comment: Of course, this will only work if the module you are looking for contains POD.

Comment: @Manni: Should work with most modules (from CPAN) as all of them are documented.

Comment: Some of them are so well documented that they have their docs in their own .pod files. It's a nice trick that works most of the time with that one little gotcha.

Comment: This only works if the module contains Pod. Strange but true.

Comment: You should use `-lm` instead of `-l`. It the's same, except that it also works if the module has no POD.

Comment: @briandfoy I think -l -m makes that work (and also gives the module path if they have a separate .pod file)

Comment: Unfortunately, on my server perldoc is not installed: "You need to install the perl-doc package to use this program."

Answer (score 54):

Quick and dirty:

```
$ perl -MXML::Simple -e 1
```

Comment: Although, if you want the version, most people say "perl -MModule\ 999".

Comment: To the anonymous editor: The correct way would be `perl -MDigest::SHA -e 1` rather than `perl -Digest::SHA -e 1`.

Comment: I use this one all the time, though i usually do a `-e "print( \"got it\n\" )"`

Comment: This is the one I like :).

Comment: this answer is better suited for use in a `shell` function: `if ! perl -M$module -e 1 2>/dev/null; then`

Comment: This really helps in discarding any subsequent warnings/errors thrown if we were to use `cpan -l` to verify modules

Answer (score 22):

```
$ perl -MXML::Simple -le 'print $INC{"XML/Simple.pm"}'
```

From the [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) entry on [`%INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%INC):

> - **%INC**
>
> The hash `%INC` contains entries for each filename included via the `do`, `require`, or `use` operators. The key is the filename you specified (with module names converted to pathnames), and the value is the location of the file found. The `require` operator uses this hash to determine whether a particular file has already been included.
>
> If the file was loaded via a hook (e.g. a subroutine reference, see [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) for a description of these hooks), this hook is by default inserted into `%INC` in place of a filename. Note, however, that the hook may have set the %INC entry by itself to provide some more specific info.

Answer (score 19):

For example, to check if the DBI module is installed or not, use

```
perl -e 'use DBI;'
```

You will see error if not installed.
(from http://www.linuxask.com)

Answer (score 12):

If you want to quickly check if a module is installed (at least on Unix systems, with [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) as shell), add this to your .bashrc file:

```
alias modver="perl -e\"eval qq{use \\\$ARGV[0];\\\\\\\$v=\\\\\\\$\\\${ARGV[0]}::VERSION;};\ print\\\$@?qq{No module found\\n}:\\\$v?qq{Version \\\$v\\n}:qq{Found.\\n};\"\$1"
```

Then you can:

```
=> modver XML::Simple
No module found

=> modver DBI
Version 1.607
```

Comment: I love this. Thank you.

Comment: This also works on Korn. But seriously, you need a hobby.

Answer (score 9):

What you're doing there is not recursing into directories. It is only listing the modules in the root directory of the `@INC` directory.

The module `XML::Simple` will live in one of the `@INC` paths under `XML/Simple.pm`.

What he said above to find specific modules.

`CPAN` explains how to find all modules here, see [How to find installed modules](http://www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html#How_installed_modules).

Answer (score 3):

> while (<@INC>)

This joins the paths in @INC together in a string, separated by spaces, then calls glob() on the string, which then iterates through the space-separated components (unless there are file-globbing meta-characters.)

This doesn't work so well if there are paths in @INC containing spaces, \, [], {}, *, ?, or ~,
and there seems to be no reason to avoid the safe alternative:

```
for (@INC)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're running [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/) under Windows:

- `C:\>ppm query *` to get a list of all installed modules
- `C:\>ppm query XML-Simple` to check if `XML::Simple` is installed

Answer (score 0):

I believe your solution will only look in the root of each directory path contained in the @INC array.  You need something recursive, like:

```
 perl -e 'foreach (@INC) {
    print `find $_ -type f -name "*.pm"`;
 }'
```

Comment: This doesn't properly quote `$_`; if it contains spaces, it'll break at the words; if it contains `;` it'll break the command ([shell injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection)) - quote using either `String::ShellQuote` or the not-quite optimal solution of using the `quotemeta` built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Bravo for @user80168's solution (I'm still counting `\`'s !) but to avoid all the escaping involved with aliases and shells:

```
%~/ cat ~/bin/perlmod
perl -le'eval qq{require $ARGV[0]; } 
    ? print ( "Found $ARGV[0] Version: ", eval "$ARGV[0]->VERSION" ) 
    : print "Not installed" ' $1
```

works reasonably well.

Here might be the simplest and most "modern" approach, using [`Module::Runtime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Runtime):

```
perl -MModule::Runtime=use_module -E '
     say "$ARGV[0] ", use_module($ARGV[0])->VERSION' DBI
```

This will give a useful error if the module is not installed.

Using `-MModule::Runtime` requires it to be installed (it is not a core module).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cpan -D module`. See [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/cpan#-D-module-%5B-module-...-%5D)

In your case `cpan -D XML::Simple`.

It will tell you where the module is installed as well as if it is up-to-date.