# Unable to locate DBI.pm module in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, centos, dbi

I am using CentOS, and I have installed Perl 5.20 and Perl 5.10 was present by default.

I am using the Perl 5.20 version to execute the Perl code

I am trying to use the DBI module and get this error

```
[root@localhost ~]#perl -e 'use DBI;'
Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBI module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.20.1/i686-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.20.1 /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.20.1/i686-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.20.1 .) at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
```

- How to check for all installed versions of Perl?
- How do I check whether the DBI or any module is installed?
- How to resolve this error so that I can use DBI module?

Comment: Have you installed the DBI module for your version of perl? Because the system module isn't going to work for you.

Comment: How to install DBI module for my version of perl or how to check if already some DBI module is present and link it?

Comment: Why did you install your own version of perl to begin with? What version of CentOS is this (as far as I know the newest perl available on CentOS is 5.16).

Comment: I have installed it to use the latest version available.The version of CentOS is CentOS release 6.5 (Final).

Comment: @Sobrique is that the only command or do I need to run make after that.If it is installed how do I check things about it like-installed or not,version,path?

Comment: Perl has an installer/builder all packaged together. It'll install somewhere suitable - usually in a 'site perl' directory which is in your `@INC` path.

Comment: @Sobrique I have installed it and yes,it is present in site_perl folder.Can you also guide me how to check for all installed versions of perl and its modules,how to switch between them while executing a program?

Comment: Usually: default perl is `/usr/bin/perl`. New perl is `/usr/local/bin/perl`. (But depends on where you installed it when you installed it).  Replacing system perl isn't a good idea unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: "perl 5.19 was present by default" - I really don't think that's the case. Perl 5.19 has never shipped as the default version with Centos (or any sane Linux distribution). Perl 5.19 is a development version. It should never go anywhere near a production server.

Comment: Stack Overflow uses [the *Markdown* formatting syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics) to format posts. Please use it in preference to bare HTML. Check [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for assistance.

Comment: @DaveCross I'm not sure about the 5.19,how do I check the system default perl version?Now perl -v shows only 5.20!

Comment: If you haven't overwritten the system Perl then you can get the version from `/usr/bin/perl -v`. Otherwise, you can try `rpm -q perl`.

Comment: @DaveCross yes,it's not 5.19,checked with /usr/bin/perl -v,the default version is 5.10,that was a mistake,edited the original post too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to check for all installed versions of perl?

- As Sobrique suggested in comments, you should never touch system perl. I'd suggest using [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/). With perlbrew you can install different versions of perl from local user, and to check all installed versions of perl using perlbrew just do `$ perlbrew -l`.

> how to switch between them while executing a program?

Install multiple perls

```
$ perlbrew -v install perl-5.20.0
$ perlbrew -v install perl-5.13.4
```

Switch between them

```
$ perlbrew switch perl-5.20.0
$ perlbrew switch perl-5.13.4
```

See this article for more details: [Installing Multiple Perls with App::perlbrew and App::cpanminus](http://blog.fox.geek.nz/2010/09/installing-multiple-perls-with.html)

> How do I check if DBI or any module is installed?

- [How can I check if a Perl module is installed on my system from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039107/how-can-i-check-if-a-perl-module-is-installed-on-my-system-from-the-command-line)

> How to resolve this error so that I can use DBI module?

- [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)
- [A Guide to Installing Modules](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=128077)